Instance method 'get' requires that 'Never' conform to 'DefaultsSerializable', Swift Error
I'm trying to setup SwiftyUserDefaults in my project like following.
import Foundation
import SwiftyUserDefaults

public enum UserMode: String, DefaultsSerializable {
    public static var _defaults: DefaultsRawRepresentableBridge<UserMode> { .init() }
    public static var _defaultsArray: DefaultsRawRepresentableArrayBridge<[UserMode]> { .init() }
    
    case normal = "normal"
    case admin = "admin"
}

public extension DefaultsKey {
    var userMode: DefaultsKey<UserMode> { .init("userMode", defaultValue: .normal)}
}

Service class.
import Foundation
import SwiftyUserDefaults

public class UserDefaultService {

    public func get<T: DefaultsSerializable>(_ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<DefaultsAdapter<DefaultsKeys>, T>) -> T {
        Defaults[keyPath: keyPath]
    }
    
    public func set<T: DefaultsSerializable>(_ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<DefaultsAdapter<DefaultsKeys>, T>, value: T) {
        Defaults[keyPath: keyPath] = value
    }
    
}

But when I try to get default user mode from ViewModel. It gives me this error.


I would not use such an outdated swift package in the first place if I were you.

@Sweeper, you mean SwiftyUserDefaults? what do u suggest?

ReferenceWritableKeyPath<DefaultsAdapter<DefaultsKeys>, T> means that DefaultsAdapter<DefaultsKeys>.whateverKeyPath: ReturnType. You declared userMode to be under DefaultKeys and I guess DefaultsAdapter makes dynamicMemberLookup. So, may be compiler is confused with nested DefaultsAdapter<DefaultKeys> and basically assumed DefaultsAdapter<DefaultKeys>.userMode to return Never type.
